# How to authenticate curl (or Postman, or Ajax) call with Spring Cloud Gateway and Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway with Keycloak, and authentication works from browser.
But, there is no `Authorization` header with the token, but `SESSION` cookie instead.
I don't want to use cookies at all, but token instead.

Currently, if I post to `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token` to get tokens and try to put `access_token` in `Authorization` header with `Bearer` it doesn't work, but returns login page.

Also if I add `keycloak.js` to browser page, and after successful login try to add `xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token);`
to Ajax call, it again returns login page.

So how to use Spring Cloud Gateway with Keycloak, from any client with provided valid token at all?

Here is my gateway configuration, and web app behind it with `/web/` route doesn't have any security applied. Keycloak is configured with basic public client.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        http.oauth2Login();
        http.logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));
        http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/web/private").authenticated()
                .pathMatchers("/web/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated();
        http.headers().frameOptions().mode(Mode.SAMEORIGIN);
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make requests to Spring Gateway with access token you need to make it a resource server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66923312/11122338